# HOW to connect my UPS with my android device

Tags: android, microcontroller

I need to connect wifi connected android device with a wifi connected UPS,so that they can communicate with each other like device can be used to know whether UPS is turned on or not any many other transaction of UPS. SoI want to know what to study or how to connect these2 items... I am thinking of using NSD(Network Service Discovery) or GCM(google cloud messaging) will any one of these suits my project..???

Comment: Ask the manufacturer of your UPS. Nobody else can help you.

Comment: if supported by linux then you can probably extract the knowledge from the linux driver and then apply it to your application.

Comment: I just want to know what method should I use to make my android device communicate with a microcontroller via internet...!!!